# Show different number of column per row in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I have fetched some list of destinations cities from database and want to show it in view.

here is my normal approach

```
<?php
$this->db->select('*');
$citydata = $this->db->get('cities')->result_array();

foreach ($citydata as $citydatas){?>

<div class="col-lg-4">
<img src="<?=$citydatas['banner];?>" />
</div>

<? } ?>
```

Above code will display 3 columns in each row,

But What i want is different approach, I need to show 2 columns in first row, then 3 column in second row.

and

Another Approach would be - three column in first row but first column will take half screen and other two will take another half and in second row first two will take half and then third will take rest half screen using col-6

here is the first grid style what i am looking for

[image: First Goal]

here is the second grid style

[image: Second Goal]

My Approach for first style, is below approach good to use?

```
<?php
$this->db->select('*');
$citydata = $this->db->get('cities')->result_array();

$i = 1;

foreach ($citydata as $citydatas){?>

<div class="<?php if($i++ == 1 || $i++ == 2){ echo "col-lg-6";}else{echo"col-lg-4";}?>">
<img src="<?=$citydatas['banner];?>" />
</div>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: You need CSS and JS.

Comment: _need to show 2 columns in first row, then 3 column in second row. and three column in first row_ - not sure how many columns your want in first row...

Comment: @Yousaf - I have corrected the question, i have separated both approach and also i have pasted two different images for both the goal that i want. i hope it may clear your confusion.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov : Can you suggest me with some example codes. i am using bootstrap4 in my template.

Comment: @Happy Voyaging How many grid style you want only two or more?

Comment: As far as I remember, Bootstrap has multiple col-lg-* classes. If not you can use CSS grid layout: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov : I am already using Bootstrap for that, the above template i have pasted is i created myself using bootstrap, but my question is how to use this in foreach loop.

Comment: @KUMAR : yes i want these two grid style only, i already have created this style using Bootstrap, but how to display like this in foreach loop.

Comment: @Happy Voyaging try `Yousaf` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nth-child` selector along with CSS grid to get the desired result.

**First Grid Style**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
}

img:nth-child(6n + 1),
img:nth-child(6n + 2){
  grid-column: span 2;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/40/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/50/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/60/400" />
</div>
```

**Second Grid Style**

For second grid style, you just need to change the `nth-child` selector, rest of the code will be same.

```
img:nth-child(6n),
img:nth-child(6n + 1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
}

img:nth-child(6n),
img:nth-child(6n + 1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/40/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/50/400" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/60/400" />
</div>
```

**PHP Code**

Use following code to render this layout using PHP

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <?php foreach($citydata as $citydatas): ?>
    <img src="<?=$citydatas['banner]?>"/>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already created that template using bootstrap, but how to implement the same desing or layout in foreach loop, 

thats my question.

Comment: if i follow your approach, then How can i add the span2 class in first item and 6th item in foreach loop.

Comment: @Yousaf sir the user uses the `php foreach loop` for displaying the images result , so what he do?

Comment: @Yousaf : Your Answer is helping, But as i am using Bootstrap classes already,
is it good to use iterate and assign classes to each result according to iterate value,

like i have updated in my question.

Comment: in this case, using `nth-child` selector is better than conditionally adding classes

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother, i accept your answer for such approach..it will help others too.